# Using print without enter in the tail

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

When I try to do this:

```
print 'asd'
print 'bsc'
```

The result is:

```
asd
bsc
```

(asd and bsc on two separate lines)...

Because SQL Server adds a '\n' after each print command.

What I want to do is print the two words one after the other one ('asdbsc').

How can I do this? I know that I can do 'asd' + 'bsc' and I get the same result but I want to use 2 separate prints.

Any idea?

Comment: `print 'asd' + 'bsc'`? I don't believe you can control this aspect of `print`.

Comment: I wrote in the post that I don't want to do that.

Comment: I don't believe there is a choice.

Comment: Strings over 4000 characters cannot be printed in SQL SERVER. I have a procedure that splits a string of over 4000 characters in strings of smaller size that can be printed. The problem is that I get the '\n' in the middle of my large string, between 2 prints, and I do not know how to remove it.

Comment: If you break it up on word boundaries, you should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to suppress the newline from the PRINT statement, but you can create a procedure to output the data instead without the line feed - [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/bdill/archive/2007/09/29/sql-server-print-max.aspx) is an example that chunks large output and outputs them without extra line feeds, which is what I think you want.